# Watching the InputScope of a TextBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer, inputscope

How do we grab the event that is generated when the inputscope of a TextBox is set to search and the Arrow is pressed?

Comment: Please, one question per question.  Also, no need to fill the title with tags!

Comment: the form submission did not allow it to be posted. it was a very short question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.There is an event OnKeyDown where you can check what key is pressed

```
textBox.OnKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // perform search
        e.Handler = true;
    }
}
```

2.ScrollViewer automatically scrolls to focused textbox, I guess...

Comment: Thank,s but it doesn't scroll automatically when asked to focus. anything I need to look out for. it's a credit card details page.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Still need an answer for the scrollviewer though. is there a way to manually scroll it?